AutoComplete from another Workbook and multiple AutoComplete

AUTOCOMPLETE FROM ANOTHER WORKBOOK

According to the code from this thread I wanted to create similar code but in a source another workbook.
Workbook is in different location.
I have tried this modifications:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cel As Range, match1 As Range, match2 As Range, rg As Range, targ As Range
Dim filePath As String

filePath = "P:\Projekty_Zakonczone\KOM PLIKI\LISTA KLIENTÓW.xlsx"
    '***Please adjust the next two statements before using this code!***
Set targ = Intersect(Target, Range("E11"))
Set rg = Workbooks("filePath").Sheets("LISTA KLIENTÓW").Range("LISTAK")


If targ Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo errhandler    'If code encounters an error, turn events back on

For Each cel In targ
    If Not IsError(cel) Then
        If cel <> "" And Right(cel, 1) <> Chr(10) Then
            Set match1 = Nothing
            Set match1 = rg.Find(cel & "*", lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)  'Match is case insensitive
            If Not match1 Is Nothing Then
                Set match2 = rg.FindNext(after:=match1)
                If match2.Address = match1.Address Then     'Code is fooled by identical strings in two cells
                    cel = match1 'Only one match found. Use it to "autocomplete" the cell
                Else    'More than one match found. User must enter more data. Return to "Edit" mode
                    cel.Activate
                    Application.SendKeys ("{F2}")   'Begin editing after last character entered
                End If
            Else    'No matches found. Do not change entered text
            End If
        Else    'Strip the line feed from the end of the text string
            If cel <> "" And Right(cel, 1) = Chr(10) Then cel = Left(cel, Len(cel) - 1)
        End If
    End If
Next cel

errhandler: Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

The error is always at the line: Set rg = Workbooks("filePath").Sheets("LISTA KLIENTÓW").Range("LISTAK")
Any Ideas?

MULTIPLE AUTOCOMPLETES
And this one is beyond my knowledge.
In same Sheet I need actually two codes for two different range and two different sources.
First one is for E11 cell and with sourse in pilepath LISTA KLIENTÓW.xlsx.Range("listak") - like above.
Second one is for cells P4 till P30 with source in filepath LISTA STANOWISK.xlsx.Range("listas")

Could someone help to combine those two requests together?
According to MULTIPLE AUTOCOMPLETE: Any of my combinations fails. I have tried just simply copying whole sequence and changing all DIM names. Does not work.
I probably missing something in syntax.
